# CherryPy / Mako path issue with %include on Linux (works on Windows)

Tags: python, linux, include, cherrypy, mako

I have an application with the following files

```
/path_to_app
   app.py
   /html
      page.html
   /js
      page.js
```

In app.py I load and render a mako template.  The template file is page.html in the html directory.  That page contains contains a line:

```
     <%include file="../js/page.js" />
```

which is intended to find and include the appropriate page of javascript (after performing mako substitutions on that file).  This works fine on my Windows development machine but when I deploy to a Ubuntu linux server for further testing it throws the error: **TemplateLookupException: Template uri "../js/fund_page.js" is invalid - it cannot be relative outside of the root path**.

changing the include to make it absolute to the application root:

```
     <%include file="/js/page.js" />
```

doesn't help, that returns the message: **TemplateLookupException: Cant locate template for uri u'/js/fund_page.js'**.

What change is necessary to be able to use this mako include on Linux, and is it possible to express it in a fashion that will be compatible with both Windows and Linux?

Comment: Just a note: this behaviour was introduced with Mako 0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using the simple expedient of moving the included js file into the same directory as the html file that calls it.

Answer (score -1):

You should add the parent directory of "js" to the `directories` parameter of your TemplateLookup instance. For example:

```
mako_lookup = TemplateLookup(directories=[ root + "/project/templates",
                                           root + "/public"])
```